# Multiple Pivot Table - R (table)

Tags: r

I have the following:

```
Type  State 
A     California
B     Washington
A     California
A     California
A     Washington
B     New York
```

I would like to do a pivot in R to find out the number of each type in each state.

I have figured out how to find out the number of each type (without state breakdown) by using:

```
table(df$Type)
```

This gives me the following result:

```
Var1 Freq
A    4
B    2
```

However, I would like to add a second dimension such that I can get a state breakdown of the above result. A suggested output would look like this:

```
  California  Washington New York   Total
A     3            1         0        4
B     0            1         1        2
```

Does anyone know how to do something like this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reshape2` to reshape your data into the correct format:

```
library(reshape2)
df1 <- dcast(df, Type ~ State)
```

To get it in the format with the row sums as listed in your question you simply need to make a few manipulations:

```
# add rownames
rownames(df1) <- df1$Type
df1$Type <- NULL

# calculate rowSums
df1$Total <- rowSums(df1)
```

And this will have the expected output:

```
  California New York Washington Total
A          3        0          1     4
B          0        1          1     2
```

Comment: Thanks @chappers! Worked well :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `dplyr`

```
    library(dplyr)

    df %>%
      group_by(Type, State) %>%
      tally()
```

Comment: This is close to what the OP asked for. If you add `%>% spread(State, n, fill=0)` you get everything except the `Total` column.

Answer (score 0):

`table` can handle multiple variables.

```
table(mydf)
#     State
# Type California New York Washington
#    A          3        0          1
#    B          0        1          1
```

Use `addmargins` to get the totals.

```
## Row totals
addmargins(table(mydf), margin = 2)
#     State
# Type California New York Washington Sum
#    A          3        0          1   4
#    B          0        1          1   2

## Row and column totals
addmargins(table(mydf))
#     State
# Type  California New York Washington Sum
#   A            3        0          1   4
#   B            0        1          1   2
#   Sum          3        1          2   6
```