# R pivot table for summing outcomes of overlapping sets?

Tags: r, pivot-table

Below is the "head" of my datatable, called off.

```
            callgroup agent_idx binary_outcome
1715         8       453              0
1716         5       486              0
1717        50       367              0
1718        60       513              0
1719         7       282              0
1720         8       660              0
```

Each row represents a specific agent, callgroup, and binary outcome (sale/no sale).
I'd like to find the sum of binary outcomes for each agent:callgroup pair. Ideally, the output would look something like:

```
callgroup  agent_idx  total_succeses
8          453        25
8          486        37
...
```

I've seen a couple semi-similar questions on here, such as [Multiple Pivot Table - R (table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419246/multiple-pivot-table-r-table) (only the binary outcome summation is not observed.) And another, with a completely different approach [How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group)

Here is my best attempt:

```
off %>% group_by(c(callgroup, agent_idx)) %>% 
  summarise(successes = sum(binary_outcome))

>>>
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` can't be recycled to size 1409261.
i Input `..1` is `c(callgroup, agent_idx)`.
i Input `..1` must be size 1409261 or 1, not 2818522.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt is almost correct, but you don't need to use `c()` in `group_by()`. Try this instead:

```
off %>% 
  group_by(callgroup, agent_idx) %>% 
  summarise(successes = sum(binary_outcome))
```

Comment: Ah, so close! Thanks :)

Comment: You can select this answer to mark the question closed if your issue is fixed :)

Comment: I will! Apparently, I need to wait 10 min to do so. Weird..

Answer (score 1):

Your method (corrected as stlba mentioned) is a way to do it, but I prefer **dplyr::count** as below.

```
off %>% count(callgroup,
              agent_idx,
              wt = binary_outcome,
              name = "total_succeses")
```